# VBA - getElementById works for simple website but not another?

Tags: html, excel, vba, parsing

So I'm currently stuck at getting a VBA script to retrieve the value of an input box from [this Sudoku website](http://www.websudoku.com/). However, I was able to get the value from a paragraph element with the id of "contact" from my own simpler website, using the same code (after switching the url and id names, of course).

Any attempts to research further brings up articles/blogs that discuss what I've done correctly so far, so I suspect I am not researching it properly.

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim sudokuCell As Object
Dim url, id, content As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

ieApp.Visible = True

url = "http://www.websudoku.com/"
ieApp.navigate url

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.document

If ieDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Nothing")
'Else
'    MsgBox ("Something")
End If

For i = 0 To 8
    Set sudokuCell = ieDoc.getElementById("f00")
    content = sudokuCell.innerText
    MsgBox (content)
Next i

ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

And here is an example of the html for a cell which is blank:

```
<td class="g0" id="c00"><input class="d0" size="2" autocomplete="off"
name="8iz6n11" maxlength="1" onblur="j8(this)" id="f00"></td>
```

And here is one for cell that is prefilled with a number:

```
 <td class="f0" id="c10"><input class="s0" size="2" autocomplete="off"
 name="s8iz6n21" readonly="" value="7" id="f10"></td>
```

I have tried both the "c00" an "f00" without success. Also, while I believe the problem at hand is I am not retrieving the element, I am concerned that the .innerText property won't retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: The website is using FRAME, so you are not accessing the frame document in the VBA code actually. You need to navigate to the actual URL given below - change your url variable as the following (which is the frame's src property):

```
url = "http://view.websudoku.com/?"
```

Second: Those are INPUT elements you are trying to get values, you should be better using Value property instead innerText

```
content = sudokuCell.Value
```

Third and last: I have no idea what your code is supposed to do inside the loop as  it will keep reading f00 element value as is. However I believe you'll loop through the input elements and just hit the wall here about the FRAME issue I explained above, so I assume loop is your part and have no trouble about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, it works great. As for the loop, that was just me fiddling with the id and seeing if that might have been the problem.

Comment: What if I didn't know the website url before hand? I.e. suppose I had the script do a search for "online sudoku" and pick the first link and that was it? And assuming I know the id's before hand somehow. Would I have to retrieve the url and reconstruct it?

Comment: Glad to hear it helps. For this sample - page, you can get the frame's src property. iedoc.getElementsByTagName("frame").item(0).src If you know the id, iedoc.getElementById("frameId").src